# Is it possible to use hand cursor in evince?

Tags: pdf, evince

Default cursor in Evince is text selection.

Is it possible to use a hand cursor (which support dragndrop) instead?

Comment: Drag and drop from where to where? Evince to Gedit maybe?

Comment: @Parto: Sorry, it wasn't clear enough. I mean the situation when you click with middle mouse button; It shows a hand which takes the page.

Answer (score 11):

As Nephente says, the middle mouse button does that.

From help documentation (Evince document viewer):

> Dragging the page around with your mouse, as if you are grabbing it. To do this:
>
> - Move the mouse pointer over the page and hold down the middle mouse button to drag it around.
> - If you don't have a middle mouse button, hold down the left and right mouse buttons at the same time, then drag.

Comment: But the middle mouse button is so prone to break, I prefer not using it at all! To have a "hand" button/option would be preferable, in my opinion. And left+right doesn't work to me.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + 1

OR

Tools --> Browse brings up the hand tool !

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure we used to be able to add extra tools, one of them was that hand tool that was handy for moving the page around the screen. I don't know what happened to it, but I'd guest the Gnome developpers pushed again for minimalism and dropped it or made it a dconf hidden setting ? ;)

Comment: At least in version 3.14.2 of evince, the middle mouse button, or alternatively left+right mouse button, allow dragging the page around.

Comment: @Nephente But the middle mouse button is so prone to break, I prefer not using it at all! To have a "hand" button/option would be preferable, in my opinion. And left+right doesn't work to me.

Answer (score 0):

With putting two fingers on my notebook touchpad it works like hand tool. but for slow and soft move it's more like bending fingers on the touchpad instead of moving them up and down.

Or two fingers, one just hold and still but another finger moves up and down.
With clicking on the right and left touchpad buttons at the same time hand tool shows itself on the screen, and with the third finger on the touchpad, I could move the page.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions to use the middle mouse button, or if you're missing a middle button, to press both the left and right buttons at the same time, come straight from the Envince documentation: https://help.gnome.org/users/evince/stable/movingaround.html.en

Like Rodrigo, I don't have a middle mouse button, and the other method doesn't work for me.  However, there are alternatives to Envince.  I downloaded Okular.  It has a hand tool.